# how to Debbuging sharepoint 2007 feature with spitemeventreciever code in visual studio 2008 with break points

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, sharepoint

Hi i developed a small code in sharepoint which will copy one list items to another list,when i debug in visual studio to track error ,the break point isn't firing .Initially it was working fine but later on i did not know happened,it is not working,i did all the ways like (1)modifying in web.config file ,(2)placing GAC (3)Adding PDF in to GAC MSIL Folder(4)attaching process to the managed code (5)i have copied DLL and PDB file in virtual directory of my application ,tried all the ways,
But non was worked..if any one have the solution to this issue kindly let me know ,i am very happy person if i get one..i lost three days on this issue

thank you
Balu

Comment: Did u Restart your Visual Studio ? OR Restart your machine if possible ? also try to reset the iss after gac the DLL in assembly folder

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you perform an IIS reset after each build. The GAC code is cached.

In VS Post-Build event, I have this in my projects.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe"  /i $(TargetPath)
```

iisreset

This will perform the task for you. Then just refresh the site and attach to the w3wp.exe for the web site.